# SQL Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException while inserting data

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans, jdbc

> SQL Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
>   Incorrect syntax near 'st'.

This is the data insertion part of the code of my whole program.I guess the exception lies somewhere here

```
String SQL;
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            SQL = "INSERT INTO formtable (clgname,clgaddres,hmob,hemail,pmonth,pyear,sname,gender,dob,paddr,smob,semail,tenboard,tenyop,tenper,tendiv,twscboard,twscyop,twscper,twscdiv,bscbcaboard,bscbcayop,bscbcaper,bscbcadiv,mscboard,mscyop,mscper,mscdiv,frsem,scsem,thsem,frthsem,hardware,os,languages,dbms,communication,stporganization,stpobjective,stphardware,stpsoftware,stpduration,othertraining) VALUES ('"+combo1+"','"+ta1+"','"+text1+"','"+text2+"','"+combo2+"','"+text3+"','"+text4+"','"+rbdtext+"','"+date+"','"+ta2+"','"+text5+"','"+text6+"','"+tboard+"','"+tyop+"','"+tper+"',"+tdiv+"','"+twboard+"','"+twyop+"','"+twper+"','"+twdiv+"','"+bsbcboard+"','"+bsbcyop+"','"+bsbcper+"','"+bsbcdiv+"','"+mscboard+"','"+mscyop+"','"+mscper+"','"+mscdiv+"','"+fsem+"','"+ssem+"','"+tsem+"','"+fosem+"','"+text7+"','"+text8+"','"+text9+"','"+text10+"','"+text11+"','"+text12+"','"+ta3+"','"+text13+"','"+text14+"','"+text15+"','"+ta4+"')";
            int rowsEffected = stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
```

Comment: Can you print your `SQL` string and execute your query directly on database and see does it create problem? And it is advisable to use `PreparedStatement` for this type of query to avoid [`SQL injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: it looks like one of your value might have `'` hence the error. please use parameters which is the correct implementation instead of string concatenation

Comment: the problem is here "+tdiv+"' you miss single quates there

Comment: @NamanGala - i am trying that

Comment: thanx for the help.. still trying.. if any more error occurs will post soon.. but really thankful to all for showing interest n helping me.

Comment: happy to help you. and please verify this type of silly mistakes  before posting it in stackoverflow

Comment: sorry. was in extreme hurry. that's why posted it.

Comment: just a small query. i am taking the date of birth field using jcalendar. the datatype for date of birth field is nvarchar(50). the data inputted is not showing in the database. so can you kindly tell, what correction do we need to make in the database design or the code?

Comment: Don't concatenate values into a query like this. It opens you up to SQL injection and unexpected syntax errors like this. Use `PreparedStatement` and set the parameter values. See [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 1):

you miss a single quotes in the query
 in `"+tdiv+"'`

it should be

```
'"+tdiv+"'
```

use the following query

```
String SQL;
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            SQL = "INSERT INTO formtable (clgname,clgaddres,hmob,hemail,pmonth,pyear,sname,gender,dob,paddr,smob,semail,tenboard,tenyop,tenper,tendiv,twscboard,twscyop,twscper,twscdiv,bscbcaboard,bscbcayop,bscbcaper,bscbcadiv,mscboard,mscyop,mscper,mscdiv,frsem,scsem,thsem,frthsem,hardware,os,languages,dbms,communication,stporganization,stpobjective,stphardware,stpsoftware,stpduration,othertraining) VALUES ('"+combo1+"','"+ta1+"','"+text1+"','"+text2+"','"+combo2+"','"+text3+"','"+text4+"','"+rbdtext+"','"+date+"','"+ta2+"','"+text5+"','"+text6+"','"+tboard+"','"+tyop+"','"+tper+"','"+tdiv+"','"+twboard+"','"+twyop+"','"+twper+"','"+twdiv+"','"+bsbcboard+"','"+bsbcyop+"','"+bsbcper+"','"+bsbcdiv+"','"+mscboard+"','"+mscyop+"','"+mscper+"','"+mscdiv+"','"+fsem+"','"+ssem+"','"+tsem+"','"+fosem+"','"+text7+"','"+text8+"','"+text9+"','"+text10+"','"+text11+"','"+text12+"','"+ta3+"','"+text13+"','"+text14+"','"+text15+"','"+ta4+"')";
            int rowsEffected = stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
```